# What's the binary file format used by MS DOS?

Tags: dos, portable-executable

I was always thinking MS DOS is also using **PE** for binary executable until recently when spotting this:

> A PE image file begins with a MS DOS
>   stub. It was used so that when a
>   program is run in MS DOS, it would
>   give a good error message (that the
>   program must be run in windows)
>   instead of crashing MS DOS.

So it implies **PE** isn't for MS DOS,then what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file) and [MZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable).

Comment: Since it's self contained, is it very huge?

Comment: @COMer: Generally, no. In fact, for fairly obvious reasons, anything over ~600K is fairly unusual (though, with overlays, larger was certainly possible). There's a reason UIs (in particular) with rather...bare by modern standards.

Comment: @COMer: No, not really. Libraries during those days were pretty much non-existent, so DLLs weren't necessary. And COM even had a limit of 64k per executable.

Comment: What's the extension of `COM` and `MZ` in those days? Is it `.exe` ?

Comment: @COMer: `.com` and `.exe` respectively.